# Evaluate FastText embeddings

Tags: word-embedding, fasttext

I want to evaluate my FastText model (trained on my own corpus).

For semantic meaning I understand that we can use a dataset containing several pairs of two words which have been scored by humans, and see how close our model is to the "human score" e.g [this](https://github.com/NLPatVCU/Sentiment-Classification/blob/master/keras_test/keras_test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gensim/test/test_data/wordsim353.tsv)

The issue is that FastText does not model the semantic meaning i.e `car` and `carrot` should be closer than `car` and `train` (if I'm correct).

Does such a dataset exist for FastText, or can we do it in any other way (instead of doing it manually be random looking at specific words)?

Answer (score 0):

As the criteria for whether FastText word-vectors are "good" is the same as for other word-vectors, you don't need a set of tests specific to FastText.

The Python Gensim library's word-vector support, in its class `KeyedVectors` (& specialized subclasses like `FastTextKeyedVectors`), includes a couple of methods for scoring the quality of word-vectors by some popular evaluations.

The method `.evaluate_word_pairs()` ([docs](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/keyedvectors.html#gensim.models.keyedvectors.KeyedVectors.evaluate_word_pairs)) uses human-scored word pairs like you've described. Its method documentation mentions some sources of word-pair data, and one such tiny (353-word) file, `wordsim353.tsv`, is included in the Gensim installation's `test_data` directory for some of Gensim's unit tests.

The method `.evaluate_word_analogies()` ([docs](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/fasttext.html#gensim.models.fasttext.load_facebook_vectors)) tests word-vectors on the same sort of analogy-solving used in the original word2vec papers, and the same `questions-words.txt` file used in those evaluations is also bundled in Gensim's `test_data` directory.

So, you can load FastText vectors into Gensim & perform these evaluations, with standard word-lists used by other published work.

If you want to test FastText's unique ability to construct synthetic guess-vectors for out-of-vocabulary words, be sure to load the vectors from a FastText `.bin` file – the `.vec` files only include full-word vectors – and use a Gensim method like [`load_facebook_vectors()`](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/fasttext.html#gensim.models.fasttext.load_facebook_vectors).